# Rebinding of Gridview after data insert via ajax

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a simple HTML page in **.aspx** and I am calling a static web method from a **.cs** file.

Now my HTML .aspx page has a Gridview which is loading on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridviewBind();
} 

protected void GridviewBind()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select name,cost,description FROM products", con);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        GridView1.DataSource = dr;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

What I want is to refresh the gridview after the the ajax call for webmethod (which is inserting new data in product table).

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveProduct(string name, string desc, float cost)
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = conn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO products(name,description,cost) Values (@name,@description,@cost)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", desc);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cost", cost);

            int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (rowsAffected == 1)
            {
                msg = "Poduct Saved Successfully";

            }
            else
            {
                msg = "Something Went Wrong...Please Try again later!!!";

            }

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        msg = "Something Went Wrong...Please Try again later!!!";
    }

    return msg;
}
```

Ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Products.aspx/SaveProduct",
                    data: "{'name':'" + name+ "','desc':'" + desc+ "','cost':'" + cost+ "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                        clear();
                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call your binding function `GridviewBind()` again in your `if` condition for successful insert. Like this :

```
if (rowsAffected == 1)
{
   msg = "Poduct Saved Successfully";
   GridviewBind(
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually gridview  is a non static member and webmethod is static so its not accessing the method. I also tried by making object, but its throwing excception at GridView1.DataSource = dr;

Comment: In that case, one option would be to write the entire code or to make a static method itself for your binding function.

Comment: so same function copied as static? No offense, but Isn't it bad idea?

Comment: It is. it will bring code repitition. Is there any hardcore need to make `Save` method as static ?

Comment: Actually I dont know ASP .Net that much, for calling ajax I am using the same method which I read from tutorial. Will a non static web method work here??

Comment: Yes. Give it a try. Remove the `static` word from method declaration line and then add a call to your binding function like I have in my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: no removing static, will result in ajax call fail. It cant find the web method.

Comment: Add the code for ajax call as well to make things more clear.\

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78759/discussion-between-sumit-and-harveyspecter).

Answer (score 0):

Use UpdatePanel In GridView.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridviewBind();
        }
}


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatepnl" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
        ---Put Your Grid View Code---
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />      
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: So instead of <asp:GridView>, I should use <asp:UpdatePanel>??
or I have to wrap my GridView inside UpdatePanel??

Comment: Sorry... I dont understand as I have low knowledge in .net. I am using <asp:Gridview>... So what are you suggesting <asp:UpdatePlan>. where I put that. Please elaborate little more. Thank you.

Comment: try  <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />      
        </Triggers>.